# How can I save the build result of the Github Actions docker image

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

Is it possible to save the build of the Github action so that it does not download this action the next time, then the problem is that I created an action that collects php with certain settings and everything is in the docker image, it takes about 2 minutes to beat the date image, which is a lot, since in subsequent executions, it makes no sense to rebuild the whole image and use the result of the build of this image.
[image]

Is there some way to cache it or save this docker build of the file somewhere?

Comment: Can you include the source code for your workflow in your question? I've posted an answer, but I can add more detail if I can see your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native caching - GitHub has an action for this: https://github.com/actions/cache .

You'd place this caching step before your build step.

Essentially you'd create a key from a hash of a file (e.g. a manifest file) or directory. Then, the Cache action would check if that key matches the key of the cache. If it matches, the cache is reloaded. If it doesn't match, then in your build step, you'd include an `if` directive with something like `steps.build-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` to ensure that the build step only runs if the cache is invalid.

The [`docker-layer-caching`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-layer-caching) action is built on `actions/cache`, and can be used to cache separate build layers of your Docker container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand this action caches files, such as composer or node_modules, but I still have to install `composer` or `node` in the docker container to execute `composer validate` or a script like `npm run build`? Or I did not quite understand from the documentation how it works.

Comment: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-layer-caching solution that helped me, edit your answer to this action because in fact it is built on actions/cache and your answer helped me find this library

Comment: Done! That's a cool action - I wasn't aware of it! I definitely use this for my work 